# How to receive and parse a json data from jsp?

Tags: java, json, ajax, jsp, servlets

I send a json from servlet like that

```
User profileUser = userService.get(id);
request.setAttribute("profileUser", profileUser);
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
try {
    json.put("profileUser", profileUser);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.getWriter().write(json.toString());
```

And in javascript in ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    cache : false,
    type : "GET",
    url : "UserServlet?id=" + userId,
    success : function(result) {
        alert(result.profileUser);
    }
});
```

The result of alert is giving me Entity.user but if I want to call result.profileUser.uuid or property of that user returns me undefined . Can anyone please help me?

Comment: What's the actual HTTP response?

Comment: @SLaks 302 moved temporary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're sending json to your Ajax client, then you need to specify that you're about to recieve json type. Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    cache : false,
    type : "GET",
    dataType : "json",
    url : "UserServlet?id=" + userId,
    success : function(result) {
        alert(result.profileUser);
    }
});
```

That will cause your success method to evaluate the result parameter as json object.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Ajax to following:

```
$.ajax({
    cache : false,
    type : "GET",
    url : "UserServlet?id=" + userId,
    success : function(profileUser) {
        alert(profileUser.uuid);
    }
});
```